# Transaction fails during smart contract deployment from Remix IDE, while i confirm the transaction from MetaMask

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, metamask

I am able to connect to private ethereum network and able to do the transactions from Metamask, but while deployment of smart contract from remix IDE, it launches MetaMask and i get below error while I confirm the transaction. Please guide.

```
ALERT: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":3682247715857,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["*****************"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: invalid sender
```

I am deploying very basic and first smart contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract MyFirstContract {
    string private name;
    uint private age;

    function setName(string newName) {
    name = newName;
    }

    function getName() returns (string) {
    return name;
    }


    function setAge(uint newAge){
    age = newAge;
    }

    function getAge() returns (uint){
    return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify your set-up better. Are you using Geth?

Comment: Yes i am using geth and golang, i have done mining on the private ethereum network. I have more than 1000 ETH balance in my account generated via mining in pvt eth network. successfully able to do the txs from MEtamask with pvt accounts, however not working the smart contracts deployments
P.S, I am able to do the same transaction on Ropsten network successfully.

Comment: As you are trying to deploy contract on private ethereum network. Choose **web3 provider** option from _Environment_ dropdown in Remix IDE.

Comment: Yes i did use Web3 provider option.

Comment: Why do you pass trough metamask? You should go directly on the RPC if using the direct web3 provider link. Something is different from what you think it is... check again

Comment: Did you unlock the account you are using?

Comment: Yes, I ensured to unlock them. but weird thing I found is I need to unlock it multiple times, before doing every transaction

Comment: @Rick, I am at a very initial stage of demo setup. And at this stage, I am clueless about which software or web3 providers to go with or, which topology or software packages would be the best fit for demo and ethereum private network setup. Please advise if you have any best suggestions

Comment: Yes, it should not make sense to have metamask in the between when you are on a local RPC with unlocked funds in Remix: you could be able to use “web3 provider” directly, giving the local address of your RPC in the prompt box that come out. At that stage you manage your accounts directly from Remix and you do not have prompts from metamask in the between.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, appreciate your tips!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This could be a lot of things. A couple of questions, are you using Ganache? If so did you import your private keys from ganache to your metamask? If not then you will have zero eth to execute the transaction

Comment: not using ganache, imported the private keys manually. and balance from pvt ethereum network is reflected in the MEtamask account, have 1000 ETH of balance from pvt eth netowork.